# How to model voltage controlled switch in LTSpice?

Tags: simulation, ltspice, error

Having trouble making a Buck converter using two complimentary switches in LTSpice. I've got everything laid out exactly as perscribed, but when I run I get the following error:

[image]
"Can't find definition of model "SW""

I've put the model for each one right there, so I've got no clue why it wouldn't know what to do with the switches. If anyone has any ideas on how to correct that please let me know, thanks.

Comment: "SW" is a model name. Thus you should modify the "SW" to "Switch1" and" Switch2" and your "Switch1" and "Switch1" are part designator "S1", "S2"

Comment: Just a minor comment: `C2` is completely useless, unless you're adding some sort of series resistance between `V1` and `C2` (either add a new resistor, or add `Rser=<...>` to `V1`). Or add `Rser` to `C1`, that will also do, if you can live with that zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not assigning a model to your switch, but just renaming it.
In order to assign a model, you have to right click on the switch and change its value to the model name you want to use.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that was pretty simple. Its all working now thank you!